# Automotive EPB switch design - why so complex?

Tags: switches, design, automotive

The Land Rover Discovery 3 has an electric parking brake (EPB) - a geared motor and cable assembly that pulls the park brake pads in. This is far more effective than purely mechanical levers of old though far more complex and failure-prone.

It also needs a switch as input to the computer that controls the motor. Now on the Discovery, the switch assembly is a rubber/silicon membrane contact pad design, with two contact pairs for each direction (in parallel I think); 7 passives and an LED:

[image: Discovery 3 switch assembly]

It seems to me that a traditional momentary DPDT centre-off switch would have achieved the same result. Are there any engineering reasons for the additional complexity of the Land Rover design?

Comment: there most likely are some engineering reasons

Comment: Most likely reason: Cost. This design may appear complex, but in mass production, all of the parts will be extreamly low cost, as will the cost of assembly. This entire unit probably costs less in bulk than a DPDT switch.

Comment: It also looks like there are multiple configurations of this board, allowing the same board + membrane to be used with different sensitivity areas.

Comment: @user1937198 - ah, I didn't even consider that; but yes - I imagine a decent quality switch (guaranteed number of cycles, etc) is more expensive. Mind you, you wouldn't know that from the price Land Rover charge for a replacement! In my case the switch came good with some contact cleaning.